# Unable to invalidate data in jQuery DataTable when replacing rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a small jQuery Datatable that periodically updates it's rows on a one-by-one basis.  This is done by replacing the row with an "Updating" row, calling back to the server, receiving a row back as html, and replacing the "Updating" row with the new server-supplied html.  This works and the users see the updated information appear.

However, if the user then clicks on a column header the rows in the table return to the "Updating" state that they had for a few milliseconds while the update was in progress.

Here is the javascript in which I'm retrieving the row and attempting to invalidate its contents so that DataTables will sort (and display after sorting) the most-recently replacedWith() version of the row.

```
function getRow(svcName, rowId)
{
    // Mark in progress
    $("#" + rowId).html("<td colspan='5'>" + svcName + "<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw'></i></td>").addClass('info');

    // Get the HTML
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: svcName,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorText) {
                $("#" + rowId).text("Error " + errorText + " (" + svcName + ")");
                var row = $(".service-table").DataTable().row("#" + rowId);
                row.invalidate('dom');
            },
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // This response is visible in the table 
                // UNTIL I sort the table, at which time it's the temporary 
                // version of the row, above, which is restored 
                // from the dataTable cache.
                $("." + rowId).replaceWith(response);
                var row = $(".service-table").DataTable().row("#" + rowId);
                row.invalidate('dom');
                //row.draw('row');
            }
        }
    );

}
```

How can I force dataTable to be aware that I've replaced the row?

UPDATE: I've updated the code as suggested in the answer by RickL, but see similar behavior:

```
function getRow(svcName, rowId)
{
    // Mark in progress
    $("#" + rowId).html("<td colspan='5'>" + svcName + "<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw'></i></td>").addClass('info');

    // Get the HTML
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: svcName,
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var table = $(".service-table:first").DataTable();
                // get the index
                var rowIndex = table.row("#" + rowId).index();
                // get the jQuery representation of the row and replace
                var $row = $(table.row(rowIndex).node());
                $row.replaceWith(response);
                table.row(rowIndex).invalidate(); //.draw(false);
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to comments and references now in the question, I'll post another answer (with comments):

```
function getRow(svcName, rowId) {
    // Get row
    var selectedRow = $("#" + rowId);
    // Set row as in progress
    selectedRow.html("<td colspan='5'>" + svcName + "<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw'></i></td>").addClass('info');
    // Get replacement HTML
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: svcName,
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Get table
            var table = $("#grid").DataTable();
            // Get row index
            var rowIndex = table.row(selectedRow).index();
            // Change row html
            selectedRow.html($(response).html());
            // Iterate, update and reset each cell in the row
            // (this preserves sorting with new data)
            $.each(selectedRow.find("td"), function (i) {
                table.cell(rowIndex, i).data($(this).html()).draw();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Testing this, I found that with this approach, the sorting of the table columns is preserved this way (which is a good thing) as the cells themselves are updated.

Comment: Almost there!  This works using `selectedRow.html()` within the `success` function (as you wrote), but my goal is to use `selectedRow.replaceWith()` instead (because there are context classes on the `<tr>` element returned that I need).  The core of my problem seems to arise from DataTables "working" when the inner HTML is replace, but not when the entire `<tr>` tag is replaced.  I'll trying using `.html()` combined with an attempt to copy the class from `$(response)` to the existing row.

Comment: Yes, if I add `selectedRow.attr("class", $(response).attr("class"));` after setting the html, I get the results I'm after.  Thanks for putting in the time to help me out with this.

Comment: Nice one. Glad it worked (and it's quite useful to have a (somewhat involved) method to do what is, I'm guessing, quite a common DataTables piece of functionality)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do wrt "updating" state, and you seem to have two ways of selecting the row in question (class and id), but otherwise:

```
// Get reference to table
var table = $(".service-table:first").DataTable();
// Get reference to row index (NOTE you have both
// ("." + rowId) and ("#" + rowId) referenced ? This assumes id selector)
var rowIndex = table.row("#" + rowId).index();
// Get jQuery representation of row
var $row = $(table.row(rowIndex).node());
// Replace jQuery representation of row
$row.replaceWith(response);
// Invalidate DataTables representation of the row data
// and redraw (with false parameter to keep table the same)
table.row(rowIndex)
    .invalidate()
    .draw(false);
```

I haven't tested it (without further code details), but hopefully the logic should be there to work it through.

Comment: Thanks, looking at this now.  The table is a set of red or green rows representing microservices.  The "updating" state is intended to turn a row blue (and display a spinner) while the back-end is queried for the current state.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Please note that the table selector in the code selects the first table of class .service-table (which is probably the case, but you may have more than one)

Comment: Unfortunately, not working.  If I leave the code exactly as you supplied, then when `getRow()` is called, I don't see the updated row at all (just the "Updating" one).  If I remove the `.draw(false)` and just `invalidate()` the row, then I *do* see the updated row in the table until I sort the table, at which point the "Updating" row is restored (similar to the original behavior).  I'm going to update the question with the current version of the code.